# Calculate value from two field in third field

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a query, that will calculate sum of products on invoice. I have 3 tables :

- Product (with product's price)
- Invoice (with invoice id)
- Products on invoice (with invoice id, product id and number of particular products)

So in my query I take invoice_id (from invoice), price (from product),number of products sold and invoice_id (from products on invoice) and calculate their product in fourth column. I know I should use 'Totals' but how to achieve that ?

Comment: Is amount the total dollar amount that the product cost, or is amount the price? You should really be storing the price and amount in the `products_on_invoice` table in addition to the `product` table so that you can *change the product's price* without affecting past `products_on_invoice` entries.

Comment: amount is the number of products with particular id on invoice. So each line looks like this : invoice_id product_id amount(of products with product_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following added to your SELECT should do it.

[Product].[price] * [Products on invoice].[number of products on invoice] AS Total

If you include the fields and table names, I can give you a much more accurate statement.

Edit:

```
SELECT 
  invoice.invoice_id, 
  product.price, 
  products_on_invoice.amount, 
  product.price * products_on_invoice.amount AS Total 
FROM 
  invoice INNER JOIN 
    (products_on_invoice INNER JOIN 
      product 
    ON products_on_invoice.product_id = product.product_id) 
  ON invoice.invoice_id = products_on_invoice.invoice_id
```

Comment: tables : invoice (invoice_id), products_on_invoice (invoice_id, product_id, amount), product (product_id, price). But if using SQL query I guess there should be some joins in there to set invoice_id from invoice table as invoice_id in products_on_invoice table ?